# Flask/Python render only a table in template

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask

I want a search bar in my site. This get data from a postgresql database with the user input, return the results and show it in a table.

How i can send the data to my .py and return the new data and render only the table with the results?

I'm using python 2.7

EDIT:

**edit_person.html**

```
{% extends "layouts/layout_logged.html"%}

{% block body%}
    <a href="/macro_test" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">TEST</a>
    <form>
      # here can the user add something from the search results 
    </form>

    {% include "searches/clothings_search_result.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**person.py**

```
@app.route('/macro_test', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def test():
    user_input = request.form["search"]

    search_result = # here the query
    search_result = [dict(r) for r in search_result ]

    result = get_template_attribute('searches/clothings_search_result.html', 'result ')

    return result('search_result')
```

**clothing_search_result.html**

```
{% macro result (search_result) -%}
     {{ search_result[0] }}
     # here is the table i want to render
{%- endmacro %}
```

Comment: Please read the Flask  [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)

Comment: Done. But there are only ways to render the complete site. I know how i send data to .py, but i don't want redirect to another site.

Comment: Can't able to figure out where is wrong without seeing your codebase. Can you add relevant code here?

Comment: @RajaSimon its to long to post it in a Coment.

I only want to render this in my .html wich is extends my main.html
`{% include "searches/clothings_search_result.html" %}`

this i call with a link:
`<a href="/macro_test" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">TEST</a>`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49898842/edit) your question to include more information...

Comment: If you don't want to replace the whole page with a newly rendered one you need to do the request with JavaScript and replace the part of the page where the search result should show up at the client side. Then you only need to render the fragment with the result on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way how it works.

**edit_person.html**

```
{% extends "layouts/layout_logged.html"%}

{% block body%}
    <a id="search_btn" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">TEST</a>
    <form>
      # here can the user add something from the search results 
    </form>

    <ul id="search_results"></ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**person.py**

```
@app.route('/macro_test/<string:user_input>/debug=<string:debug>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
    def test(user_input, debug):

        search_query = # here my query

        # get data and make dict
        search_result = sql_conn.query(search_query)
        search_result = [dict(r) for r in search_result]

        # t = true
        # other = false

        if debug == 't':
        # show pretty json
            return jsonify(search_result)
        else:
            # default =  convert all unknown types to str
            return json.dumps(search_result, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)
```

**edit_person.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#search_btn").click(function()
    {
        $.getJSON( "http://192.168.178.31:8080/macro_test/test/debug=f", function( data ) {

         var items = [];

             $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                items.push( "<li>" + val.clothes_inventory_number + " - " + val.clothes_date_return +"</li>" );
             });

            $("#search_results").html(items.join( "" ));

        });
    });
});
```